# KnockoutJS, batch update observableArray?

Tags: javascript, dom, mvvm, knockout.js

I have following scenario:

A list of items represented by observableArray, besides the content/title etc. I would like to make each of them collapsible in view.

Now the problem becomes if I should store this state as each item's observable: **if so how do I implement a trigger that toggle all items open/close efficiently** - ie. minimize the dom update.

**ko.utils.arrayForEach** seems like the way to go, does it trigger view refresh only at the end of loop? is there a better way?

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
    ...
    item.close(true);
    ...
});
```

**EDIT**: this is what's happening in the DOM (inside the knockout foreach loop)

```
<div class="item">
    <!-- ko 'if': !close() -->
    <div class="article" data-bind="html: article"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

So basically I can click a button somewhere on this page, which run ko.utils.arrayForEach that toggle all items. It works, I just don't know if it's the best way (eg. only trigger dom update once instead of for each item).

Comment: If your view contains elements that depend on the number of items visible, you should use a computed observable in combination with the [throttle-extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html). Otherwise, the `arrayForEach` version is just fine because there is nothing to "minimize" concerning the necessary DOM updates (each item needs to be shown/hidden, what do you want to optimize there?).

Comment: I think my previous example is confusing people, updated now...

Comment: What do you expect a "minimized DOM update" to look like? Somehow, still all elements need to be added/removed or shown/hidden. And somehow, this has to happen one after the other. So there is nothing to optimize there (only if you have elements that are affected by EVERY item change).

Comment: I am thinking about issues like this: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html - when I toggle all of the item off, for example, ideally I want the model to notify the view once, not N times.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind you need to implement a filtering. Create new filtered array based on your array and show items depend on your property.

```
vm.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function (fitem) {
        if ('open' == fitem.state()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}, vm);
```

Change `state` property in an appropriate event for each item and bind `filteredItems` to your list control.

Check out [next example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html) for more details